# Difference between ＆and & Character Encoding

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters

I am building a CAML query and some of my values have

"＆" which translates to "＆" in U2U CAML Builder

However when I try to match the items in my list that have "&" it fails.

When I input "&" into the valeus it translates to "&"

What is the difference between "＆" and "&" and how in code (vb.net) should I account for the difference?

Comment: ＆ =  Unicode Character 'FULLWIDTH AMPERSAND' (U+FF06)

Answer (score 3):

The character is Unicode U+0026 &​ ampersand (`38decimal, HTML: &#38; &amp;`), this is inherited from the same value in ASCII. Apart from this, Unicode also has the variants:

```
* U+FE60 ﹠​ small ampersand (HTML: &#65120; )
* U+FF06 ＆​ fullwidth ampersand (HTML: &#65286; in block Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms)
* U+214B ⅋​ inverted ampersand (HTML: &#8523; )
```

**info:**

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff06/index.htm

**More Information:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand

I hope its help to you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue right now and after a little research, I found out, that SharePoint saves Taxonomy values with ampersand (&) as fullwidth ampersand (＆) (unicode). 
You can convert your search query values (&) with `TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName()`  in fullwidth ampersand (＆) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.normalizename(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)  and vice versa with `string.Normalize()` (see [Convert fullwidth to halfwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149458/convert-fullwidth-to-halfwidth#25149897))

A good article about SharePoint ampersands you can find here:

https://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-converts-ampersand-and-double-quotes-to-unicode/

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, ＆ is the character FULLWIDTH AMPERSAND, whereas & is a just plain AMPERSAND. The Unicode database declares these characters to be *compatible*, which means that if you convert both ＆ and & into the NFKD normal form, you will end up with the same result (specifically, &). If you wish to treat ＆ and & as if they were the same character, perhaps you could find a function that converts your strings into NFKD.