# Convert fullwidth to halfwidth

Tags: c#, unicode

In C#, how do I convert a string that's using fullwidth form characters into halfwidth form characters?

For example, given `userInput` below, I want to convert `Ｓｔａｃｋｏｖｅｒｆｌｏｗ` to `Stackoverflow`:

```
string userInput= "Ｓｔａｃｋｏｖｅｒｆｌｏｗ";
//string userInput= "Stackoverflow";
```

Comment: Create a mapping (i.e. a `Dictionary<char, char>`) that tells you which character belongs to the other one and then translate character-by-character.

Comment: @AlexD That page’s formatting is a joke, right?

Comment: Seriously? Or is this a joke?

Comment: @poke That's certainly one option, but I'm betting there might be an easier way. Perl seems to have a built-in function for this particular conversion. For C#, I'm pondering maybe `NFKC` string normalization?

Comment: @AlexD Well, I didn’t comment on the content. And I just don’t get why people even bother publishing such things when it is not only barely readable but the formatting completely breaks the content (the code has lots of syntax errors).

Comment: @AlexD You might want to post this key point as an answer then? :)

Comment: Do you mean something like `userInput.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `string.Normalize()` method:

```
string userInput = "Ｓｔａｃｋｏｖｅｒｆｌｏｗ";
string result = userInput.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
//result = "Stackoverflow"
```

See example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TOsjAB).

More information on the Normalization Forms can be found on [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Comment: typo: `test.` should be `userInput.`